# I want to rotate simple 3D object in iPhone

Tags: iphone, 3d

I want to rotate a simple 3D object (lets say an animal) in my iPhone application. I don't have experience with 3D programing or Game engines. Since I have to finish the task ASAP can anybody say where can find very simple code for this task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

Use the following link load 3D obj file and rotate it.

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/wavefront-obj-loader-open-sourced-to.html

Comment: The *"... and rotate it"* part is exactly what he wants to have explained how it is done (plus displaying of course).

Comment: Thanks It is working fine, I want to change the background color to Clear color, I tried by setting the view (GLView) color to Clear color but didn't change the background color. Please let me know how can I change it.